# I'm trying to change an image using GD library but it's not working?

Tags: php, image, gd

```
<?php
header('content-type:image/jpeg');
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('suliduli.jpg');
//alpha channel parameter omitted below as it is optional.
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 50, 0, 0);
imagejpeg($image, '', 90);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

I know that I have gd installed; I checked using php info! And the file suliduli.jpg is there as well, could there be any problem I'm not seeing

EDIT: this is what i get when I remove the header:

> ÿØÿà�JFIF������ÿþ�;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 90 ÿÛ�C�     ÿÛ�C    ÿÀ�)³"�ÿÄ����������� ÿÄ�µ���}�!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ�������� ÿÄ�µ��w�!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á #3RðbrÑ $4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ���?�ûŽŽ}èïKíÖ¿ ?P¤Á§šBÜÔÜBÒsNÇ ü´Ä5ºSw§nÇJF<ç¡¨°ÐšSžÝ)¬{àÑŸCHa‘Ò“¾i„SF{Ò´œŠ@CPF9Í`íÚ€Ô)�Í_B‰Jj5¥4œš›ˆxmÝ;RŽ¹Í3ÕH,>“?5ëGðÓ$pÏ4ÑëNÜ1A^8 QG8¥Ýòâ™C·u¤¤ù}éÞÔ‰¶”Œ÷ ô¢ªÀ �‡ŽôíÜS ÍHÆŸJŒŽiì:Spsš à½Í#zŠPÛš›Ÿj¾arG?¥4cÞœzP/Nþ´Š#lƒùÓr}*B8¤�æŽRî!ëIÀ?ÖŠÉŒkb›Ñiã¦M4óÓ¥HÑ_½HÓj®kr.¦íNãîÒãw#PÇLSq÷³R²ÿ�‘L ã’*‹LnE›‡­¬3tµ47 ôÅ"õ¨æg˜?#E Ö™ž:RîÀïZ °½ñšU¤ÛÓÑ•ëEÄ8u94ŒÍžqŠC×šü .R@3×ŸjCÖ”œãŽÜRÏJ’ƒwnô¹‡å ¢€‚E#t£ï ‚…£¥&01ÚŒŒõ ~4”ŒÚ7S¸¬-<éL¥ÝéUqX r7ËÍG¸u"Ô\v$'¡¥�ñÍ0‘ž)Á¹5} °¥¨94Æ?7µ�’j‡bAîiàû“Q®3É§·éŠObž0i8¦n ÑƒsØçÿ�ÕJ2N0*M¤»åÅ*·Ô!‡@sô§ŽsŸÐS‡c‚(<âžÔOJÓ˜Bçð4ßó¤#<šCzŠÏ¨ëHI8©ç=y ¢‚„áýè?74m,iØcyÏ¥}zÓÿ�ÏÍHWqÉô­q¼çéHÃÒ—qaÍ;øhÑÿ�ë¦ãœÓÀß¼1XYÜ¤Äë’zÓ)ì#ô¤#i©{”®OjaÃtëÞžqM$R#8ëÉ¤?8|ÄÓ[å4!ËÓ¥FÝsÛÞ¤=*21MˆËôT»EùŠ¹©¸zQIŽ:Ò“Æk.Vyã‡JPz{R”ÓòŠØ@ô¤­)8¤aP0Î{Òšo/JaäsLãôn¥ÝƒKAˆNÕÅ Ò“†OZLñÇj’‡f°Í&H"ƒÏOZÃÃqŠhù†iÛp2 4‘Ú´¹"î´cÞ˜|Ó‚ädVeº—­4ü¼S‡J'C€8§Ò“Fixn:SóÍqÜâ¬CØýi¤qÍ1åŒ³cšñŸŽ“Á¦§K—Ò©v¸¿QÒœ æìéQ•YYŸ­x·JÐPý¶ò(=ràšó~Ò>ÒžH­¦Sä�Cýkâ?|TÔukÉd“Íu'z²¾Öæ¹—ñÌ—é>ùW…cóÀ½k¾v×¾zQ£J«Ÿ[7íKiª¼æUu.ßèÌ•Æþµ®Ÿµå¥ÁE{XWæùŽGÒ¾8Õuˆï-•>×þ?z‹›£§Ù$Aßv7 é§BähÙªRwåGÜZ/íQ£»¤7ˆè‹iéÍwv<9}qÁyµ$ÇÎÇ…úúWæt¾(¸i’BwZ3[~ñ•ü%"·œ§¤­Üÿ�Z™`Ô¾cÉBOÞGêF›¬A¨pŒ»ˆ òAÐÖš|Ã\~5ðW…þ?jú/ÙcŠáÍÌÊÖòÊëíó1¯¥¾ütÄ–öÚ±¬&ã;gN$î¬;gŠàåq÷dsÖÂ7ïRÕ¿ÔgµÔu’0èC©�‡NrÒ”‚0G=Æ?dïsËsARÇŠyRJP ŠAr,víCezSÂæ“Ú´C¸Ý»‡&½ÅÝØÐ~”Çq£­!4íÔÚ\Ã“J;Ú’—0ÈÈç˜9¥<’h&²³,—qãš Rdgü)Œ:â¡îUÆõè6Ò0ÁéOçŸZ@}E¹Úoò4âr3Þ›Œ`PZ·½¹>”P3@dŽ´ƒŠ­&ìžzPr�ûÜRíÇJnêóÞ‹ŽÃºþTÚÔ”P ¢ŠFéPPóHFy¥¤ÅÓŠLí QœRr �|ÝiTì C’2hÛÅ�IüèáO4„tÁ4æZ�M¹9­xõÇ°¥0àRtõ¥i_­í4ƒ¥L³ŸŸûÌÕÌêV2i¶¾dó”G;‘1÷Gùjö¨S¥dšÔõ¦¹$kBa+spé±É ØZ~¥u-ÄË<)]ŸwÞ²t¡yVò$«ÛwÍººßÙ»CæÚ‘7óµ>eùh«QÑ¬â¶:b¹éèŽ2ÊIloÆpì…¾Fû¼Õ«½JÞâH‚|œòÊ±ŠšïKdF"ï<ÃqVÿ�{mdjK>šê#ÑíÚ¯»œüÛ«Ð§ÖýáçJ^ÍYj\»†&¶HÑgÏ&züÕcNÓâ¸´Y`Aû¯”¬Gø¿½\å¶ ÷S0”lf;v(þèì4™ôûÇ¶ŠM›†óÏðƒEUÉf\d§Ð‚ §±ºKÔï 3î?6âq·Ú»Mâæ£gÁdFmÎª~eöÝþÕqw*Üµ¤Á”íõš‰­d³D–ÒA?šœªýÜÔÆ•9|EFNÛ^ý¢ç¸°ŠÞâæ &|³"å¤81Šö_xöãZ³Û©ÚýŠëÍ*°ŽØÍ~søS^ÊÒ¦Qa}®¹û·­}áŽ&í,-oäHV1.yr1ßx˜ŠnæH×ÙR®škSì5ÆÐ(&²ü9©_F¶¸pÃkS–¬5nèùéÅÂN/ ÇùM)]ËÅ>šW®)“q§§qƒF:Œ^3øU&8éF O)W#£Þ”ŒR¼Ô†-šGÓÀè)™Ý•­WÙ)ÀíÒŽjLÌóX4ÊÜm&O4âvÒNå ÚqøÓvœÔO½48Á¤4ÆQE[?7zSÓ¥7îô¥,V À7})xÆiÌ( C»Òn ° ­ çœf€Aäb™ßëKNÁa§µ&ï—ã×4bÄ-ÇAHXž)ÀdÒÉ>Ôr†“éBZ\âŽ§‘Òµ†—øiH=hŽ{Ñd;‹Ž:õ¤Æ;gëKJÃ“Ò>lŠCŸJyëô¤<ÕÅþJîNôÐ8ü)§¡=*[åŽgâŒ ð?…5

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting any errors? What does the result look like?

Comment: im not getting any errors, the image is not showing, and i checked suliduli.jpg again thiers not any chnages!!! :))

Comment: Is error reporting turned on? What does the result look like if you remove the header()?

Comment: What version of GD are you running?

Comment: im runnning bundled (2.0.34 compatible)  version, yeh my error reporting is on, and i edited the question, this is what i get when i remove the header @pekka

Comment: That looks like a healthy JPEG image. What happens if you change the input image? It is not by any chance a CMYK one?

Comment: no its working now for some reason!!! thanks @pekka thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your jpeg file a CMYK-jpeg?  If so, GD will not work.  They need to be RGB-based.